# Why can GNU cal (the CLI calendar utility) send email messages?

Tags: history, gnu, cal

The GNU cal utility has [an option to **send an email message to someone with its output**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/manual/gcal.html#DOCF15):

> ###### **`--mail[=address]`**
>
> Send Gcal’s output via `mail` program to the given *address*, e.g.:
>
> ```
> --mail=esken@gmx.net
> ```
>
> If no *address* is given, Gcal tries to send the eMail by using the following methods:
>
> 1. If an environment variable `MAILTO` is defined and set, the eMail is
>    send to the address which is listed in this environment variable. See
>    [Environment Variable `MAILTO`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/manual/gcal.html#x_002dMAILTO), for more information.
> 2. If above action
>    fails, and if an environment variable `USER` is defined and set, the
>    eMail is send to the address which is listed in this environment
>    variable. See [Environment Variable `USER`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/manual/gcal.html#x_002dUSER), for more information.
> 3. If
>    above action fails, and if an environment variable `LOGNAME` is defined
>    and set, the eMail is send to the address which is listed in this
>    environment variable. See [Environment Variable `LOGNAME`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/manual/gcal.html#x_002dLOGNAME), for more
>    information.
> 4. If all above actions have failed, no eMail is send.
>
> Generally, Gcal does not send electronic Mails whose message body is
> empty! An informational message will be shown on the *standard error
> channel* if this case occurs.
>
> All highlighting sequences produced by Gcal itself are always disabled
> respectively automatically converted into the according marking
> characters if an eMail must be send; no matter if the
> `--force-highlighting` option was given or not. This behavior of Gcal is an imperative necessity, because it is possible that the mail program
> cannot perform the mailing correctly. Please pay attention in this
> context to the further explanations concerning the limitations of the
> *text part* of a resource file line (see [Text part of a line](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/manual/gcal.html#Text-part-of-a-line)).
>
> If an environment variable `MAILPROG` is defined and set, its contents
> will be used as the program name of the mailer instead of the standard
> name `mail`. See [Environment Variable `MAILPROG`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/manual/gcal.html#x_002dMAILPROG), for more information.

#### What's the purpose of this?

Why was it introduced? Was it ever useful for something? Is it still useful today? I can't imagine any real use case for wanting to send *just* a calendar to somebody, without anything else in an email.

#### An example

Here's me using it to send en email to myself:

```
karol@kmb ~ % gcal --mail=karol@localhost
karol@kmb ~ % mail                       
Mail version 8.1 6/6/93.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/karol": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 karol@kmb.localdomai  Sat Mar  4 12:34  22/656   "Mail from `gcal' (04-Mar-2023 12:34:29)"
? 
Message 1:
From karol@kmb.localdomain  Sat Mar  4 12:34:29 2023
X-Original-To: karol@localhost
Delivered-To: karol@localhost
To: karol@localhost
Subject: Mail from `gcal' (04-Mar-2023 12:34:29)
Date: Sat,  4 Mar 2023 12:34:29 +0100 (CET)
From: karol@kmb.localdomain (Karol Baraniecki)


      March 2023
 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
           1  2  3< 4>
  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 26 27 28 29 30 31   
                     

?
```

Answer (score 2):

someone wanted that feature, so they implemented it.

Not everything that exists has a wide usefulness; try not to overthink it :)

I mean, you ask about a program that has an option for this:

> ```
> --atmosphere=air-pressure[,temperature]
> ```
>
> Set the base data of the Earth’s atmosphere that is necessary to calculate the amount of refraction, that is used by the Sun and Moon
> oriented special texts.

I think we can say with a probability >> 50% this feature was used by at most two people, ever.

Comment: How much of the 330-page PDF did you read ?